# Is it possible to run matlab on a remote server and control it using the matlab GUI from a thinclient?

Tags: matlab, remote-access, matlab-deployment

Akin to what can be done with emacs with slime: the core services can run on a performace grade remote computer while I can edit and run code from emacs gui on an netbook.

- Me and my colleagues often need to do some demos using machine
  learning scripts running in matlab
- This requires us to carry around heavy laptops.

Could we have the applications running on a remote server and access
   it using the same matlab gui without running the scripts locally?

Remote desktop or similar solutions are not acceptable: multiple users would like to use the same server.

This is why none of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100251/can-i-run-matlab-on-windows-with-ui-just-that-the-code-runs-on-remote-server) were helpful

Comment: Do you need the GUI in particular? You could always run `matlab -nojvm` via ssh, which will drop you into a MATLAB shell. Of course, you won't have access to GUIs or graphics doing this..

Comment: This is definitely possible, this is how I used Matlab in my graduate lab. I don't know the specifics of how it worked, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but the short answer is "yes". Hopefully someone else can tell you *how* to do it.

Comment: @PoorLuzer: What OS is the remote server running? if you are on Windows, I believe there is a license issue and you need a Windows Server edition to be able to have multiple concurrent remote desktop sessions. If you have UNIX, X11 has no such limitations, and works perfectly over SSH tunneling. Of course you can use other display-mirroring technologies like VNC and the like...

Comment: thinking about it, this question is more suitable on Super User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the best way is with **VNC**. You can start a **VNC server** on the host machine, and then access this desktop remotely from anywhere with a **VNC client**. You can disconnect and reconnect at another time, and your desktop will still be there. Also, multiple users can all have different sessions going, or can access the same one. If you don't want each session to run a full blown desktop, you can configure it to be minimal. For security, it is recommended to use an **SSH tunnel** or similar.

The exact programs will vary based on your setup, but the things to google are bolded, above.

My setup is:

- **VNC server**: `vnc4server` on a Ubuntu linux host.
- **VNC client**: *Chicken of the VNC* for mac.
- **SSH tunnel**: *SSH Tunnel Manager* for mac (although this can be done at the command line too).

Good luck!

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of a vncserver session I just started up on our cluster, with matlab running in it. I'm accessing it through the vnc client on my mac. Works great!

[image]

Comment: JOhn, this is a very well done answer! If I use this technique, will you be able to confirm if multiple remote users can use a single workstation alongwith another user sitting physically at that workstation, each not interfering with the other? The workstations are all i5-2600 with 16GB RAM running Win 7 Ultimate

Comment: @PoorLuzer Correct. The main limit will be if all the users start running enough stuff to slow down the machine as a whole. Also, since the server will be a Windows machine, it's probably worth searching a bit for windows-specific guides to see if there are any additional issues to be aware of. Good luck!

Comment: It will be a while before I can test this out, but your answer is very high quality. Accepting it

Comment: VNC is pretty bandwidth intensive though, because it sends a picture of the GUI to you. Isn't there anything faster for MATLAB specifically?

Comment: I am not sure it is the EXACT answer for the question. He wants to write on the matlab from client and run Directly on the matlab from server.@John Colby

Answer (score 2):

SSH with X-window forwarding will do the trick. It will get you the MATLAB screen you know and love but will be running everything on the remote computer. To do this, in a terminal with SSH (I like MobaXterm, though you can use Putty) you ssh via

ssh server.location.here -X

This will get you the terminal on the computer (after typing in a password), and in the terminal just type

matlab

and a MATLAB screen will show up. Note that opengl will be disabled, so your plots might not plot as fast, though you can still use gpu algorithms (i.e. cuda. Note you may need to run the command "COMPUTE=:0" before opening matlab if gpuDevice turns up empty for MATLAB's cuda).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Windows is the OS MATLAB is running on.

Comment: You can setup SSH to Windows via Cygwin, though that can be kind of tough.

The easiest solution is then remote desktop (RDP). It's pretty simple to setup. If you search in the Windows search bar "Remote Desktop" it will take you to the box you need to check to turn it on, and then you have to add an exception to the Windows firewall, but then you're good to go (if your router doesn't block the port). From a Windows computer you then search for remote desktop and it will bring you to the client, where you put in the IP of the server computer and that brings you to your Windows login screen.

Comment: As a note, RDP will log you off on your "main" screen, but if you have long code running, it will continue to run and when you log in on your remote screen it will be still running. If you use multiple monitors, RDP, and then go back to your main screen, it will move your windows all to one screen. However, that's its only downside (once you get all your network ports setup and it works) other than security. I tend to like it more than SSH because of how easy it is for monitoring code that takes a long time, and it runs Open GL on the server computer which means you have less graphing errors.